# How do I make font stand out on an ebook cover?

Tags: fonts, text, gradient

How do I make font stand out when the cover is thumbnail size, so you can read the font in thumbnail size? Do I need a bevel or gradient? I don't have a clue and I'm getting my cover done on Fiverr but you can't read my name in thumbnail as it fades into the background.

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Comment: For starters, maybe invest more than $5 in a designer.

Comment: where's the image gone?

Answer (score 2):

In very general terms, you need to achieve contrast between the text and its surroundings. You can do that by using:

- size
- color
- whitespace
- typography (font choice)

Any graphic designer worth their title will know how to apply these principles to get a working cover.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an outer glow to the text with a color inverse of the background then change the width and opacity of the glow until it's not incredibly noticeable. It ought to make a difference in the thumbnail. If you still need more pop, use unsharp mask on the flattened thumbnail.